# Android - Entry animation for items in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I would like to ask you for some references or source code where I can find out how to make an entry animation when a new item is showed in a ListView, just like google+ does it.

I only have found [this.](http://iserveandroid.blogspot.mx/2011/07/how-to-perform-entry-animations-for.html?showComment=1371516335087)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use ObjectAnimator to animate convertView the first time it is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a library by Niek Haarman that does this for you. Check this out: [ListView Animations](http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations/)